# How does Nano protect itself from transaction flooding attacks?

Tags: nano

RaiBlocks transactions do not have fees and are processed instantly, so what protects the nodes from being flooded of tiny transactions?

Answer (score 2):

From the [wiki page](https://github.com/clemahieu/raiblocks/wiki/Attacks), each transaction will be required to do around 5 seconds of Proof of Work, which will only require around 1 microsecond to validate. This means that the attacker will waste a large amount of resources while the nodes waste a very small amount.

Comment: What's preventing the attacker to modify the source code, to bring 5 seconds down to 1 microsecond?

Comment: Nothing prevents it, he could send complete junk data infact. But the nodes only take 1 microsecond to verify it is trash data. If he wants to send something valid he must do the 5 second PoW or the other nodes will notice it is falsefied data with their 1 microsecond verification.

Comment: That's not the detailed reply I hoped for. My C++ profiency is limited, but how could you verify he did 5 seconds PoW, instead of 4.9 seconds PoW, for example?

Comment: The 5 second Proof Of Work, is not an absolute value but an approximation. Bitcoin wants the network to solve blocks at an interval of around 10 minutes. If you check a block explorer you will notice that this is simply an average, sometimes there is only 7 minutes between two blocks sometimes 15. From my understanding the PoW should take around 5 seconds for someone to send valid data. One follow-up question that could be asked here which I do not know the answer is "How does the RaiBlocks network estimates 5 second PoW to send a valid transaction?"

Comment: The problem I see is how Raiblocks network protect itself against an attacker sending multiple **valid** transactions to accounts they control. The answer provided at the aforementioned wiki page is not satisfactory. It doesn't matter the ratio between verification and generation time. The issue is: will the network store all this data????